# What is the SQL statement for requesting column entries only once per entry

Tags: mysql

What would be the SQL statement to request column entries only once per entry even if there are many of the same type?

I am using MySQL (recent version).

Comment: "column entries once per entry" - what?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you want.

Comment: You *may* be looking for `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`, but this question is written in a very unclear manner (so I am confused as to if this is really what was meant or if it is just a misunderstanding of a record and record-set).

Comment: Distinct - is what I was looking for. What is wrong with the question's formulation, I am just wondering, what is the constructive criticism, so I can get an impression? - I thought of column -> entries -> all entries - once - and not duplicate. Thanks to all others too.

Comment: @user128360 I think "column entry" is an unusual way to describe a value in a MySQL table. The word "entry" at the end is also confusing. It's not a standard SQL term and it could refer to a value, a row, a query, or other things. I think people usually just call the data in a table column "values." You could also talk about "selecting values without duplicates" or "getting values only once each."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `SELECT DISTINCT` ? It makes it so that if your table includes the entries:

```
word
----
hi
hi
hello
orange
hi
banana
```

the query `select distinct word from tablename` will give you:

```
word
----
hi
hello
orange
banana
```

Here's a [quick tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) and here's the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

Answer (score 2):

do you mean something like DISTINCT?

it shows every entry only once

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/distinct-optimization.html

another possibility is GROUP BY to create groups per entry name